# How do I write this pug function in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Can someone tell me how I can write the following pug code in handlebars code?

```
ul
      for product in products
          li #{product.product}
          li #{product.price}
```

I found the following code, but I have to populate two points per iteration. So I don't know how to implement that.

```
handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(n, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(n in block)
        accum1 += block.fn(n);
    return accum;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use `{{each}}`? http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration

Comment: @Tomalak yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<ul>
{{#each products}}
   <li>{{product}}</li>
   <li>{{price}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```